# Can I scale up ImageView pixel art without further pixellation?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable

I have a series of 60x60 pixel art images in my app, and they look very crisp on a small phone.  However, on a tablet, Android tries to scale it up, which pixellates the image.

image.setFilterBitmap(false) reduces the blur, but it's still nasty looking.  Is there an easy way to scale up the pixel art so I don't have to make high res versions of all my images?

Comment: due to different screen densities, It won't be easy to achieve that with only a low resolution image. I will be better to have a high resolution one I think.

Comment: That shouldn't be too much of a problem.  I need to go look up the recommended resolutions for each category (medium, high def, extra high def, etc).  Then maybe I can just do the largest one and scale down from there.